# Nim cannot install a package

Tags: compiler-errors, nim-lang

Error: cannot open file: nimcuda
knowing that I already used the command
`nimble install nimcuda`

and installed it.
Windows
I use the command "nim c -d:release x.nim" to compile

I have tried to install it again and again but nothing workds.

Comment: Which nim version are you using (as in, are you using the current nim stable version or the devel branch)? Have you checked in your .nimble/pkgs directory (or if you use devel: .nimble/pkgs2) that nimcuda is installed? Have you tried using the -p/--path flag to define a path to search for the directory that nimcuda is in? (For docs: https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#compiler-usage-search-path-handling)

Comment: It may also be of interest to check your nim dump (as referred to in the docs) to see if the directory of nimcuda is in there (first check if it's in .nimble/pkgs as those directories will most definitely be included in nim dump)

Comment: @PhilippDoerner, reason in nimcuda package architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason here

[image: Reason]

so you should use

```
import nimcuda/SUBMODULE
```

[image]

Comment: nimcuda author uses this way also in examples: https://github.com/SciNim/nimcuda/blob/master/examples/random.nim#L14

Comment: Why do you comment on your own answer? If the information in the comment is relevant and would improve your answer, then please [edit] the answer and add that information. Comments are not meant for this.